# qlpreviewcontroller doesnt load mysql query

Tags: xcode, qlpreviewcontroller

Why qlpreviewcontroller doesn´t load my pdf file if the path is a mysql query.

for example :

http://myweb.com/ios/download.php?upl_P=699

The file appears codificated.

Advanced thanks

Answer (score 0):

QLPreviewController only works with file URLs. You have to download the file to the local filesystem first and then load it from disk using:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/file/on/disk"];
```